# Transfer error using Phantom Wallet when using signAndSendTransaction function

Tags: javascript, solana, solana-web3js

Does anyone know what's wrong with this code?

```
    await window.solana.connect();

    let fromWallet = window.solana.publicKey;
    let toWallet = new PublicKey("<KEY>");   
    
    let transaction = new Transaction();

    transaction.add(
      SystemProgram.transfer({
        fromPubKey: fromWallet,
        toPubKey: toWallet,
        lamports: LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
      })
    );

    transaction.feePayer = fromWallet;
    const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('devnet'), 'confirmed');
    let bk = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
    transaction.recentBlockhash = bk.blockhash;

    const signature = await window.solana.signAndSendTransaction(await transaction);        
    await connection.confirmTransaction(signature);
    console.log(signature);
```

It throws an error at line

```
const signature = await window.solana.signAndSendTransaction(await transaction)
```

Something about converting undefined to base58.

I have checked the keys, they are both fine.

Here is the error log:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1897 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toBase58')
    at eval (index.browser.esm.js?64b9:2451:1)
    at Array.sort (<anonymous>)
    at Transaction.compileMessage (index.browser.esm.js?64b9:2450:1)
    at Transaction._compile (index.browser.esm.js?64b9:2563:1)
    at Transaction.serializeMessage (index.browser.esm.js?64b9:2585:1)
    at ia (inpage.js:141:130205)
    at inpage.js:141:137033
    at c (inpage.js:2:47880)
    at Generator._invoke (inpage.js:2:47668)
    at Generator.next (inpage.js:2:48309)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Oh dear lord,

I fixed the issue by changing the code:

```
 transaction.add(
  SystemProgram.transfer({
    fromPubKey: fromWallet,
    toPubKey: toWallet,
    lamports: LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
  })
);
```

to the following:

```
  const instruction = SystemProgram.transfer({
    fromPubkey: fromWallet,
    toPubkey: toWallet,
    lamports: LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
  });
  transaction.add(instruction);
```

I still don't understand why it works, but hey it solved my issue.

Comment: Please don't add the first sentence referring to _Lord_; it is unnecessary.

Comment: Nah, it's fine. I'm expressing my frustration.

Comment: This shouldn't make a difference. But I got uninformative errors like this when I was using a string as a public key somewhere instead of the PublicKey object.

Answer (score 0):

The error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toBase58')` typically means that there's an invalid `PublicKey` somewhere.

Assuming that the connection to the wallet is correct, there's probably an issue with the line:

```
let toWallet = new PublicKey("<KEY>");
```

First, be sure that the result of that call is correct, by logging it, ie.:

```
console.log(toWallet.toBase58());
```

If that works, then there's likely an issue with the wallet connection.

Comment: Tried that for both keys, the keys are printed fine on the console.

Comment: I receive ... Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined